# Lodash has no method 'remove'

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, lodash

I'm following an example on `websockets` from my book:

```
var _ = require('lodash')
var ws = require('ws')
var clients = []

exports.connect = function(server) {
    var wss = new ws.Server({server: server})

    wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
        clients.push(ws)

        ws.on('close', function() {
            _.remove(clients, ws)
        })
    })
}

exports.broadcast = ...
```

The above snippet adds new websocket clients to the `clients` array. When a client closes the connection, it removes it from the list. I'm getting the following error on the `_.remove(clients, ws)`:

```
TypeError: Object function lodash(value) {
    // exit early if already wrapped, even if wrapped by a different `lodash` constructor
    if (value && typeof value == 'object' && value.__wrapped__) {
      return value;
    }
    // allow invoking `lodash` without the `new` operator
    if (!(this instanceof lodash)) {
      return new lodash(value);
    }
    this.__wrapped__ = value;
  } has no method 'remove'
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/home/user/Projects/socialapp/websockets.js:15:6)
    at WebSocket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at WebSocket.cleanupWebsocketResources (/home/user/Projects/socialapp/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:926:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

That's definitely the way it's done in my book, and I don't understand why I'm getting that error as the `remove` method definitely exists.

EDIT: I'm using `lodash` v. `3.10.1`

Comment: Which version of `lodash` is used?

Comment: @raina77ow I'm using `"lodash": "^3.10.1"`, just installed it with `npm`. Not sure which version my book is using. It's not mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some issue related to your lodash version. Try to do it this way:

```
var _ = require('lodash')
var ws = require('ws')
var clients = []

exports.connect = function(server) {
    var wss = new ws.Server({server: server})

    wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
        clients.push(ws)

        ws.on('close', function() {
            clients = _.without(clients, ws)
        })
    })
}
```

or you can simply do the same using plain old javascript

```
clients = clients.filter((client) => client !== ws);
```